# Create Xl deploy package with multiple Jenkins artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, xl-deploy, xlrelease

Is there a way to create an xl deploy package using Jenkins and then add multiple artifacts to the package? It seems that when using the xl deploy plugin, once you create a package it is not possible to add other artifacts to the package using Jenkins. I'm also using xl release which is calling a Jenkins pipeline to build the multiple artifacts if that is of any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No not directly using the plugin. The XL Deploy plugin for Jenkins is designed to create an immutable package as a post-build action which is then designed to be published to a repository (e.g. the XL Deploy repository).  If subsequent to creating this package changes are required this constitutes a new version of the package.

One approach *could* be to have several Jenkins jobs compile and/or gather each of the components and some other job (or other mechanism) build the final package from a common workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest.xml of the application, you can add the multiple artifacts as dependencies. So, the rest artifacts are deployed first and then the main application will be deployed all in one job.